# How to dump aggregated output of a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I'm working on a project. The makefile is very complex as it includes multiple other makefiles which also include other more makefiles. I would like to dump all included makefiles into a single file. How can I do that? Is there anything similar to the C preprocess dump such as '-E'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
make -p     # GNU Make
nmake -p    # Microsoft Make
make -h     # help
make -d     # debug
make -n     # just print
```

Start with a simple example and work from there. Starting on a big Makefile when you don't know anything about Make is not a good idea.

- http://www.working-software.com/node/19
- http://www.cs.clemson.edu/~duckwos/make/

Comment: I know make pretty well and I need to figure out this makefile that was created by others. I need to improve it and figure out all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `make --dry-run`:

> ```
> `-n'
> `--just-print'
> `--dry-run'
> `--recon'
> "No-op". The activity is to print what commands would 
>          be used to make the targets up to date, but 
>          not actually execute them.
> ```

Comment: Baically, i would like to figure out the dependencies of all makefiles. I'm looking for something like '-E' option for gcc.

Comment: make -p is it.  See Lumi's answer.